# To test if 1338 1 is an integer

Tags: excel, vba

If i have the following in an excel worksheetcell

```
 1338 1
```

How do I test if its an Integer, I need a function that return FALSE upon this - The IsNumeric-function returns TRUE.

*it has to do with a download from mysql-database - and sometimes the splitfunction in excel doesn't work properly. the "1" is belongning to an adjacent cell that is:*

1338 1339.01

its not a valid number. How do I test this? I cannot use IsNumeric-function because there are individual numbers in the cell, but its not an integer. I cannot make calculations of it - neither use it in a graph.

So - is there a buildtin function in vba to test if its an integer when this situation occurs?

Comment: Not sure I understand how you are testing? And why you say `IsNumeric` isn't enough? For the record if there is a space no built in function will return it as a number.

Comment: @user2140261 - I wasn't clear enough, sorry... I updated my question - actually I want a function that returns FALSE when testing "1338 1" for an integer (number).

Comment: `IsNumeric` will return false, because of the space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function to pass the value in as a string and check each character to see if it is numeric.

```
    Function isValidNumber(sValue As String) As Boolean

    Dim bResult As Boolean

    bResult = True

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To Len(sValue) Step 1
        If IsNumeric(Mid(sValue, i, 1)) = False Then
        bResult = False
        Exit For
        End If
    Next
    isValidNumber = bResult
    End Function
```

Comment: What ***benefit*** does this have over `IsNumeric`?

Comment: The **benefit** is that it will report False on 1.1, which is a number, but not an integer.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I do not see anything about decimal number though, only values with spaces. Based on the comment  I cannot make calculations of it - neither use it in a graph, wouldn't decimals still work for calculations and graphs? If whole numbers only is an issue that is a simple case of `IsNumeric(x)` followed by `x = Int(x)`?

Comment: I agree with you completely!  ................  my point is that not all "numbers" are "integers"